# How to scan wifi networks in android programming?

Tags: android, wifi

I want to know how to scan wifi networks in android programming. I'm only a beginner.

Comment: Search in _Google_ before asked

Comment: I've tried the code stated above but it has an error. Error:(73, 20) error: onMenuItemSelected(int,MenuItem) in MainActivity cannot override onMenuItemSelected(int,MenuItem) in AppCompatActivity
overridden method is final. what to do?